# Pass the initial data from ASP.NET MVC 4 controller action method ast list to initialData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have an action result within my Main controller as below:

```
    public ActionResult Reports()
    {
        List<AModel> aList = _da.GetList();
        return View(aList);
    }
```

And I want to capture it for knockout in initialData as a list of objects.

```
    //here is the issue I don't know how to pass it.
    var initialData = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
```

And I want to bind it like this:

```
     ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData));
```

Any help thanks.

Comment: Please explain what obstacle you ran into

Comment: Looking at viewBug my viewData is Null. I know there is data in aList. I have referenced my page too: @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.AModel> : issue is I don't know how to pass my model list items to my initialData.

Comment: Your approach seems correct. You're serializing to Json. Are you certain the model is populated when the view renders?

Comment: Yes I have two items that I move I double checked the controller actually genrates those as items in the list that is passed to view .. in my model I have public int id { get; set;} and couple of more just a string and a datetime.

Comment: I removed everything else and it seems to be wroking. Somehow some other script was interfereing with this I assume. Thanks for looking this up. I will let you know once I figure what was causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three was another script interfering with this. I will keep you posted once I find out what was causing this.